# Google map API - rotate polygon in z-direction

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to rotate polygon on Z-direction. Please See below image.
[image]

I got code from below post

[Google Maps API rotate Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049552/google-maps-api-rotate-rectangle)

Which is working perfectly fine to rotate polygon on X-->Y or Y-->X direction. Please see below image.

[image]

I apologize for my English to explain this problem. I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to rotate a [polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).
Create a polygon from a rectangle object and display it on the map instead of rectangle.
Rotate a polygon.

*check Investigation results on SO docs for code snippet*

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vo0yzp2t/1/

```
function rotatePolygon(polygon,angle) {
    var map = polygon.getMap();
    var prj = map.getProjection();
    var origin = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(polygon.getPath().getAt(0)); //rotate around first point

    var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map(function(latLng){
       var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
       var rotatedLatLng =  prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point,origin,angle));
       return {lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(), lng: rotatedLatLng.lng()};
    });
    polygon.setPath(coords);
}
```

And you can also refer to [When I rotate a rectangle, it's no longer rectangular](https://github.com/ahmadnassri/google-maps-polygon-rotate/issues/3).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll test it out and will post here.

Comment: This is working but I want to rotate other way. This is rotating in X--> Y or Y--X direction and I need rotation in Z-direction. I have tried to explain in above image.

Comment: rotatePoint function is missing can you add it?