# Add custom background image to draggable polygons in google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add custom background image to my draggable polygons in google Map. I've already used the Polygon class to make a draggable polygon that can also rotate. I want to add background image to it. I've read other posts and they mentioned "custom overlay" but that is a fixed image on the map which doesn't support dragging/rotation. How should I go about doing this?

Update:
  I created a custom layer with my image and added it to the map with the same coordinates as the polygon. Whenever the bounds of my polygon change, I will also update my custom layer so they always overlap. However, as shown in the gif, https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Yhn.jpg, the polygon and the image are not in sync and there's a delay.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What does the code that allows the polygon to be dragged and rotated look like?  You probably need to apply that same functionality to the image (clip it to the polygon, and allow it to be dragged and rotated along with the polygon).

Comment: draggable is a built-in option in polygon api. For rotation, i followed this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049552/google-maps-api-rotate-rectangle) and added an eventListener to rectangle. What you suggested is basically what i'm doing right now: I added a custom layer for the static image and move the image layer whenever the polygon is dragged or rotated. But those two actions are not synced so there's a delay in the animation,

Comment: You asked how you should go about doing it.  In general, that is to broad a question, but it sounds like (from your comment), you have an implementation. 
 Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself** (not just a picture of the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find solutions online so I figured it out myself with this working demo: [draggable polygon with image](https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lvc40g/2/). I made it with a combination of custom overlay and normal polygon library. You can click on the polygon to rotate and drag it around.

`plz see jsfiddle`

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds hide() and show() methods to a custom overlay's prototype.
// These methods toggle the visibility of the container <div>.
// Additionally, we add a toggleDOM() method, which attaches or detaches the
// overlay to or from the map.

var overlay;

USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();



function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 20,
    center: {
      lat: 33.678,
      lng: -116.243
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    map: map,
    bounds: calcBounds(map.getCenter(), new google.maps.Size(2.7, 20))
  });

  var rectPoly = createPolygonFromRectangle(rectangle); //create a polygom from a rectangle



  rectPoly.addListener('click', function(e) {
    rotatePolygon(rectPoly, 10);
    rectPoly.rotation += 10;
    console.log(rectPoly.rotation)
    overlay.div_.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rectPoly.rotation + 'deg)';
  });

  rectPoly.addListener('drag', function() {
    console.log('Drag end!');

    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var i;

    // The Bermuda Triangle
    let polygonCoords = rectPoly.getPath().getArray();

    for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
    }

    // The Center of the Bermuda Triangle - (25.3939245, -72.473816)
    center = bounds.getCenter();

    overlay.bounds_ = calcBounds(center, new google.maps.Size(2.7, 20))
    overlay.draw();

  });

  function calcBounds(center, size) {
    var n = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height / 2, 0).lat(),
      s = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.height / 2, 180).lat(),
      e = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width / 2, 90).lng(),
      w = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, size.width / 2, 270).lng();
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(s, w),
      new google.maps.LatLng(n, e))
  }


  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' +
    'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';



  overlay = new USGSOverlay(rectangle.bounds, srcImage, map, rectPoly);


  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map, rectPoly) {

  // Now initialize all properties.
  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;
  this.rectPoly_ = rectPoly

  // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
  // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
  // method so we'll leave it null for now.
  this.div_ = null;

  // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
  this.setMap(map);
}

/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.border = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  rectPoly = this.rectPoly_;

  // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayImage" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  // We use the south-west and north-east
  // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
  // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
};

// Set the visibility to 'hidden' or 'visible'.


function createPolygonFromRectangle(rectangle) {
  var map = rectangle.getMap();

  var coords = [{
      lat: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
      lng: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()
    },
    {
      lat: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
      lng: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
    },
    {
      lat: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
      lng: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
    },
    {
      lat: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
      lng: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()
    }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var rectPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: coords,
    draggable: true,
    rotation: 0

  });
  var properties = ["strokeColor", "strokeOpacity", "strokeWeight", "fillOpacity", "fillColor"];
  //inherit rectangle properties 
  var options = {};
  properties.forEach(function(property) {
    if (rectangle.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      options[property] = rectangle[property];
    }
  });
  rectPoly.setOptions(options);

  rectangle.setMap(null);
  rectPoly.setMap(map);
  return rectPoly;
}


function rotatePolygon(polygon, angle) {
  var map = polygon.getMap();
  var prj = map.getProjection();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  // The Bermuda Triangle
  var polygonCoords = polygon.getPath().getArray();

  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  // The Center of the Bermuda Triangle - (25.3939245, -72.473816)
  console.log(bounds.getCenter());
  var origin = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(bounds.getCenter()); //rotate around first point

  //var origin2 = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(polygon.getPath().getAt(1)); //rotate around first point


  var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map(function(latLng) {
    var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
    var rotatedLatLng = prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point, origin, angle));
    return {
      lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(),
      lng: rotatedLatLng.lng()
    };
  });
  polygon.setPath(coords);
}

function rotatePoint(point, origin, angle) {
  var angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
  return {
    x: Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
    y: Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add an input button to initiate the toggle method on the overlay. -->

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry"></script>
```